# Change public on timeline for tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Sometimes I get tagged in pictures or stories that I don't want to share with my whole audience. Can I alter who can see that story per story?

I have found a setting in privacy settings that lets me pick my audience for all tagged pictures and stories, but I cannot alter the story privacy on my timeline.

This is what I get on my timeline when I press the sharing button.

[image]